# Is it possible to get Extra Attack or equivalent without taking at least 5 levels in a class?

Tags: dnd-5e, character-creation, class-feature, multi-classing, multiattack

I am planning a Forge Domain Cleric character and think *Extra Attack* would suit them, but it seems as though multiclassing is the only way that would be possible, given that Forge Domain Clerics don't otherwise have *Extra Attack*.

However, I also want to the *Saint of Forge and Fire* feature at level 17 (assuming I survive that long) and do not want to sink more than 3 levels into a different class if I can help it.

The only ways I know of to get *Extra Attack* or an equivalent feature/ability are:

- Sinking 5 levels into a martial class such as Barbarian, Fighter, Monk, Paladin or Ranger;
- Sinking 6 levels into a class that gets *Extra Attack* via archetype feature, such as College of Valor Bard, College of Blades Bard, Bladesinger Wizard, etc;
- Sinking 5 levels into Warlock and picking Pact of the Blade and the *Thirsting Blade* eldritch invocation;
- Being a War Domain Cleric, who can make an extra attack via their *War Priest* feature at level 1, although this isn't an "always on" feature like the others, and I am already intent on taking the Forge Domain, so this isn't an option for me;
- Finding a way to cast *haste*, but that isn't an "always on" feature either and would likely require me to sink 5 levels into another spellcasting class since it's a 3rd level spell that isn't on the Cleric spell list;

Are there any other ways I'm missing, ideally that don't involve sinking more than 3 levels into another class? I would prefer "always on" methods, even if it requires using my bonus action (a la the *War Priest* feature mentioned above, although two-weapon fighting is not an option because I plan on going Warhammer and Shield), and I'll accept magic items, if there are any that let you have extra attacks.

Comment: I am noticing a lot of answers (including the accepted answer) that are actually 'the ability to attack with a bonus action', which is not actually the same as "an extra attack as part of the attack action". Was this actually what you are looking for? Or were you looking specifically for ways to add extra attacks to your attack action?

Comment: @Theik It was primarily about Extra Attack, but something else if not (since I think I was able to exhaustively list the ways to get Extra Attack specifically); hence the question title was "or equivalent" (otherwise all these answers would be wrong). Sdjz asked me about the possible use of making an attack with a bonus action via comments before posting his own answer (see my edit in the edit history).

Comment: @NathanS Are ranged weapon attacks included? Yea, I know, I'm late to the party.

Comment: @AntiDrondert Wow, yeah, this was for a character from a year ago. I mean, for the character I was building at the time, I was trying to get more use out of my warhammer, so ranged attacked were not really something I was interested in (although I ended up with a Dwarven Thrower, so in the end I kinda did have a ranged weapon attack after all), but on the other hand, this question wasn't _against_ ranged weapon attacks. The only related restriction in the text was that I planned on going Warhammer and Shield, so if the answer involved not using a warhammer, then that wouldn't fit my criteria.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Obtain a [Scimitar of Speed](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/scimitar-of-speed) which allows an extra attack per turn as a bonus action. Unfortunately this is not a warhammer like you wanted to use. You might be able to convince your DM to convert it to a *Warhammer of Speed* or simply accept it and use a scimitar instead.

Comment: Accepted this one as getting hold of a "Warhammer of Speed" is the most likely option for me, given that I dumped DEX and CHA (which most of the other answers would need me to have 13 in to multiclass into Monk or Ranger or Sorcerer, etc, good answers though they are...)

Answer (score 27):

You can dip 3 levels into Monk and get the Way of the Kensei (XGtE pg.34) tradition, that will turn your warhammer into a monk weapon and allow you to make unarmed strikes with bonus action when you attack with it.

Not exactly an extra attack but it's still an attack.

As a bonus the Agile Perry feature will give you +2 AC until start of your next turn if you make an unarmed strike with your attack action and keep holding your monk weapon.

---

Another multiclass option is Ranger as Aliden mentioned in his [answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/127772).
Paraphrasing a little:

> You can make an additional attack with [Horde Breaker](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Ranger#toc_23) or deal more damage with [Colossus Slayer](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Ranger#toc_23) if you choose the Hunter Archetype

Another archetype option is to choose the Gloom Stalker (XGtE) and get an extra attack that deals extra damage. Though that one is only for the first turn of combat so not "always on".

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80418/discussion-on-answer-by-fenrirg-is-it-possible-to-get-extra-attack-or-equivalent).

Answer (score 24):

Not sure if this fits your criteria well enough, but it's a spell I recently learned about that seems close to what you want:

The 2nd-level Cleric spell *[Spiritual Weapon](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Spiritual%20Weapon#content)* creates a floating weapon you can attack with [as a bonus action](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/55161/33777). It is not, as you say, 'always on', but it lasts for 10 rounds and is a lower-level spell than *Haste*. It does 1d8 damage (or 2d8 if you cast as a level 4 spell), so it's comparable to a martial one-handed weapon.

The biggest catch is that the spiritual weapon can only move 20 feet per round, so you could potentially find yourself leaving it behind if you move a lot. But on the other hand it doesn't need to be next to you, so it offers you more range.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80417/discussion-on-answer-by-daaaahwhoosh-is-it-possible-to-get-extra-attack-or-equiv).

Answer (score 11):

You can take three levels of Ranger, choosing the Hunter archetype at level 3. This gives you access to Colossus Slayer, which deals an additional 1d8 damage when you hit a foe that is not at maximum HP, or Horde Breaker, which allows you to make an additional attack against another creature that is within 5' of the target and in range of your weapon.

These are both somewhat situational, but unless you're fighting a lot of enemies you can one-shot, Colossus Slayer will be active most of the time.

Answer (score 7):

There's no ways of getting the **Extra Attack** class feature in less than 5 levels, but there's still a few ways of getting more attacks or extra damage. Some have already been said, but the closest would be (in my opinion):

- Sorcerer 3 with the Quickened Spell [metamagic](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/sorcerer#Metamagic-372) option and the [*booming blade*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/booming-blade) (or [*green-flame blade*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/green-flame-blade)) cantrip from the *Sword Coast Adventurer's Guide* (p. 142-143). The metamagic allows you to cast the cantrip as a bonus action for 2 sorcery points. The cantrip also deals extra damage in addition to your regular weapon attack.
- [Polearm Master](https://www.dndbeyond.com/feats/polearm-master) feat (PHB, p. 168). It grants you an additional attack as a bonus action every turn. It can also be combined with the [Great Weapon Master](https://www.dndbeyond.com/feats/great-weapon-master) feat (PHB p. 167), though as a Cleric you might be a bit short on ASIs.
- Monk 2 for the extra unarmed attack as a bonus action from the [Martial Arts](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/monk#MartialArts-227) feature, and [Flurry of Blows](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/monk#Ki-228) for 2 unarmed attacks as a bonus action (for 1 ki point).
- Barbarian 3 with [Path of the Berserker](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/barbarian#PathoftheBerserker) for the Frenzy ability which allow you to make an attack as a bonus action while in a rage. While the exhaustion at the end of the rage can be a big drawback, it can be mitigated with the use of [*greater restoration*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/greater-restoration).

Another option could be the [Magic Initiate](https://www.dndbeyond.com/feats/magic-initiate) feat (PHB, p. 168) to grab the *booming blade* (or *green-flame blade*) cantrip. It won't allow you to make an extra attack like with Sorcerer 3's Quickened Spell, but it will give your single attack a few extra damage dice over the course of your career, allowing you to almost keep up with the damage output of more combat-focused classes.

Answer (score 4):

While not exactly "Extra Attacks", there are a few options you can look into with **Feats**.

Mage Slayer, Sentinel, and Martial Adept all give you means of attacking using reactions rather than part of an attack action, and only Martial Adept has a limitation on number of uses.

With your criteria, I'd recommend looking into a homebrew magical item.

Answer (score 3):

Two levels of Moon Druid will let you Wild Shape into a Brown Bear with Multiattack.  That's probably not at all useful for your build, but it's *kind* of like an extra attack.

Answer (score 2):

I have sort-of a solution to get an extra attack. I've been working at the same build and unless you're locked-in on race options and weapon preference you could use a [Double Bladed Scimitar](https://www.dndbeyond.com/equipment/double-bladed-scimitar):

> **Double-Bladed Scimitar**
>
> Martial weapon, melee weapon
> 100 gp, 6 lb.  2d4 slashing - special, two-handed, Special.
>
> If you attack with a double-bladed scimitar as part of the Attack action on your turn, you can use a bonus action immediately after to make a melee attack with it. This attack deals 1d4 slashing damage on a hit, instead of 2d4.
> Two-Handed.

This weapon requires two hands to use. This property is relevant only when you attack with the weapon, not when you simply hold it.
Source: ERLW, page 21. Also found in WGE, page 74.

**There are two races that are proficient with the weapon:**
the Elf (High; Valenar)Source: WGE, page 73, and the Elf (Wood; Valenar)Source: WGE, page 73.

Being a forge priest you could technically just craft your own DB Scimitar since it's within the 100gp limit (and you can make it +1 and magical!)

Could roll a few levels using a scimitar + shield, it'd be a finesse DEX build. Take [Revenant Blade](https://www.dndbeyond.com/feats/revenant-blade) at 4th lvl to make it a finesse weapon as well.

> **Revenant Blade**
>
> Prerequisites: Elf
>
> [...]
>
> - A double-bladed scimitar has the finesse property when you wield it.

Source: ERLW, page 22. Also found in WGE, page 74.

It seems a little redundant in some cases- having to wait for level 4 for a DEX build to come online, but it is an option. And honestly I prefer to grow into my concepts as well. Maybe you're an Elven smith prodigy who rediscovers the lost forging techniques and fighting style through communing with your ancestors?

Distinctly I chose this route since the weapon carries the stigma that the wielder of such a weapon would be challenged by the elves of Valenar whether you're worthy of wielding it.

Comment: Hi Robert, welcome to rpg.se! Take the [tour] and visit the [help] or ask here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) for more information. This is a great first answer, well done on providing so much supporting information. Thanks for contributing and happy gaming!

Answer (score 1):

Choose the [Shifter](https://www.dndbeyond.com/races/shifter) race, Longtooth subrace.

Racial feature grants a bonus action bite attack while shifted, you can shift once per short rest.

**Shifting**

> As a bonus action, you can assume a more bestial appearance. This
>   transformation lasts for 1 minute. When you shift, you gain
>   temporary hit points equal to your level + your Constitution modifier. You also gain additional benefits
>   that depend on your shifter subrace, described below.

**Longtooth Shifting Feature**

> While shifted, you can use your elongated fangs to
>   make an unarmed strike as a bonus action. If you hit with your fangs,
>   you can deal piercing damage equal to 1d6 + your Strength modifier,
>   instead of the bludgeoning damage normal for an unarmed strike.

This would give you a bonus attack action at level 1 and you can be any class you want.