# Is Extra Attack based on class level or character level?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, fighter, character-levels

If you had a rogue at level 4 and then multiclassed to a fighter at level 5, would the character then have 2 attacks since he has 5 total levels or would you have to level fighter to level 5 to gain the extra attack?

Comment: Which game system are you referring to, Mike?

Comment: As Pyrotechnical notes, we need to know what game you’re playing in order to answer any rules question. Please always include the appropriate system tag, e.g. [[tag:dnd-5e]] for D&D 5th edition (the latest), to your question.

Comment: Semi-related: [Is it possible to get Extra Attack or equivalent without taking at least 5 levels in a class?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/127743/is-it-possible-to-get-extra-attack-or-equivalent-without-taking-at-least-5-level)

Answer (score 5):

### You unlock the extra attack based on Fighter level, at 5th level.

Unlike cantrips and proficiency bonuses (PHB, p. 15) that increase with character level, this is a *class feature* that unlocks with class level.  (Cantrips increase damage dice at levels 5, 11, and 17 which match the "Tiers of Play" on PHB p. 15).

> **Extra Attack**
>   Beginning at 5th level{Fighter}, you can attack twice, instead of once,
>   whenever you take the Attack action on your turn. (PHB p. 72)

That's a continuation of the larger heading of "Class Features" that begins on page 71 of the PHB.  The Barbarian, Monk, Paladin, and Ranger also get an extra attack at class level 5 (PHB, p. 49, 79, 85, and 92 respectively under Class Features).  The Rogue does not.  (PHB, p. 95-97)